# Generate different text in every tile javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have arrays of strings with names and surnames. I created username which consist of random name and random surname and I want to display different username in every generated tile. I tried to splite names and surnames and than add it do array and get random array index but it didn't work. Better solution would be to use my "username". Biggest problem is that I can't modify my getData() function - it always assign the same username to each tile.

```js
function createGrid(x, y) {
    for (var cols = 0; cols < x; cols++) {
        for (var rows = 0; rows < y; rows++) {
            console.log(namesArr)
            console.log(x*y)
            numberOfTiles = x*y;
            var randonIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfTiles);
           // $(".usernameSpace").html(namesArr[randomIndex]);
            //Doesn't work here
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'><div class = 'usernameSpace'></div></div>");
        };
    };
    $('.grid').width(800 / x);
    $('.grid').height(800 / x);
};
function refreshGrid() {
    var x = $("#colsNumber")[0].value;
    var y = $("#rowsNumber")[0].value;
    $('.grid').remove();
    createGrid(x, y);
};

function getData(count) {
    var names = ["Michal ", "Jan ", "Katarzyna ", "Andrzej ", "Jozef ", "Bartek ", "Mikolaj ", "Tomasz ", "Julian ", "Brajan ", "Dzesika "];
    var surnames = ["Noga ", "Kowalski ", "Nowak ", "Pazura ", "Duda ", "Komorowski ", "Tomczyk ", "Jozefowicz ", "Lechicki ", "Goldberg "];
    result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var randomNameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        var randomSurnameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * surnames.length);
        var name = names[randomNameIndex];
        var surname = surnames[randomSurnameIndex];
        result.push({
            name: name,
            surname: surname
        });
    }
    return result
}

function textDisplay() {
    var numberOfTiles = 12;
    //for (i = 0; i <= numberOfTiles; i++) {
    var data = getData(12);
    //var username = "";
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    username = "";
    $.each(data, function (i, { name, surname }) {
        username += ` ${name} ${surname}`;
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // }

    namesToDisplay = "";
    surnamesToDisplay = "";

    $.each(data, function (i, { name }) {
        namesToDisplay += `${name}`;
    });

    $.each(data, function (i, { surname }) {
        surnamesToDisplay += `${surname}`;
    });
    console.log(username)
    console.log(namesToDisplay)
    console.log(surnamesToDisplay)

    //$(".usernameSpace").html(username);
    namesArr = namesToDisplay.split(" ");
    console.log(namesArr)


    $(".usernameSpace").html(namesArr[2]);
}
function AssignUsername(Class, content) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName(Class);
    $(container).html(content);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".startBtn").click(function () {
        refreshGrid();
        textDisplay();
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
 margin:auto;
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
}
.grid{
 outline:5px solid white;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
    background-color: #212121;  
 display:inline-block;
 color: white;
}
.input{
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #757575;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 3px;
    height: 4%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
}
html {
 font-family: 'Arial';
}
.startBtn{
 background-color: #4b4b4b;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
}
#textDisplay{
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="MetroUI 03'2018 basic.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="MetroUI 03'2018 basic.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="textDisplay()">
<p>
    Give me width of grid:
</p>
<div>
    <input class='input' id='colsNumber' type='number'>
</div>
<p>
    Give me height of grid:
</p>
<div>
    <input class='input' id='rowsNumber' type='number'>
</div>
<button class="startBtn">START!</button>
<div class='nameDisplay'></div>
<div class="Container"></div>
<div id = "container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when you do:

```
$(".usernameSpace").html(namesArr[2]);
```

You are assigning all titles with that class to the same HTML values. Instead iterate through your titles and assign it a value based on your `data` variable:

```
$(".usernameSpace").each(function(idx){
  $(this).html(data[idx].surname);
});
```

Although I'd recommend storing the names directly in the `data` attribute of the `.usernameSpace` elements as you create them. Then you could just use `$(this).data("surname")` when you iterate through your elements. That way will be more safer as well in the event that `data` and the number of `.usernameSpace` elements differs, along with that it will make the code simpler.

[*Here is a fiddle example of what I described above*](http://jsfiddle.net/wj2qgLmh/7/)

```js
function createGrid(x, y) {
    for (var cols = 0; cols < x; cols++) {
        for (var rows = 0; rows < y; rows++) {
            console.log(namesArr)
            console.log(x*y)
            numberOfTiles = x*y;
            var randonIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfTiles);
           // $(".usernameSpace").html(namesArr[randomIndex]);
            //Doesn't work here
            $('#container').append("<div class='grid'><div class = 'usernameSpace'></div></div>");
        };
    };
    $('.grid').width(800 / x);
    $('.grid').height(800 / x);
};
function refreshGrid() {
    var x = $("#colsNumber")[0].value;
    var y = $("#rowsNumber")[0].value;
    $('.grid').remove();
    createGrid(x, y);
};

function getData(count) {
    var names = ["Michal ", "Jan ", "Katarzyna ", "Andrzej ", "Jozef ", "Bartek ", "Mikolaj ", "Tomasz ", "Julian ", "Brajan ", "Dzesika "];
    var surnames = ["Noga ", "Kowalski ", "Nowak ", "Pazura ", "Duda ", "Komorowski ", "Tomczyk ", "Jozefowicz ", "Lechicki ", "Goldberg "];
    result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var randomNameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        var randomSurnameIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * surnames.length);
        var name = names[randomNameIndex];
        var surname = surnames[randomSurnameIndex];
        result.push({
            name: name,
            surname: surname
        });
    }
    return result
}

function textDisplay() {
    var numberOfTiles = 12;
    //for (i = 0; i <= numberOfTiles; i++) {
    var data = getData(12);
    //var username = "";
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    username = [];
    $.each(data, function (i, { name, surname }) {
        username.push(` ${name} ${surname}`);
    });
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // }

    namesToDisplay = "";
    surnamesToDisplay = "";

    $.each(data, function (i, { name }) {
        namesToDisplay += `${name}`;
    });

    $.each(data, function (i, { surname }) {
        surnamesToDisplay += `${surname}`;
    });
    console.log(username)
    console.log(namesToDisplay)
    console.log(surnamesToDisplay)

    //$(".usernameSpace").html(username);
    namesArr = namesToDisplay.split(" ");
    console.log(namesArr)


    $(".usernameSpace").each(function(idx){
      $(this).html(username[idx]);
    })
}
function AssignUsername(Class, content) {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName(Class);
    $(container).html(content);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".startBtn").click(function () {
        refreshGrid();
        textDisplay();
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
 margin:auto;
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
}
.grid{
 outline:5px solid white;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:none;
    background-color: #212121;  
 display:inline-block;
 color: white;
}
.input{
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #757575;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 3px;
    height: 4%;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: white;
}
html {
 font-family: 'Arial';
}
.startBtn{
 background-color: #4b4b4b;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
}
#textDisplay{
 height:800px;
 width:800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="MetroUI 03'2018 basic.css">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="MetroUI 03'2018 basic.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="textDisplay()">
<p>
    Give me width of grid:
</p>
<div>
    <input class='input' id='colsNumber' type='number'>
</div>
<p>
    Give me height of grid:
</p>
<div>
    <input class='input' id='rowsNumber' type='number'>
</div>
<button class="startBtn">START!</button>
<div class='nameDisplay'></div>
<div class="Container"></div>
<div id = "container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In place you used surname "$(this).html(data[index].surname);", why can't I use my "username"?

Comment: @MikołajPrzenzak You will want `username` to be an array as it's currently a large concatenated string. I've updated my answer to use `username` after changing it to be an array of strings. I'd still recommend the second approach though, the current one can't scale past 12 blocks. I'll update it to use `name + surname`.